# javaToWs generating xsd from extended class

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl

I have some classes which I use as return type in wsdl operations.

something like:

```
@WebService()
@XmlSeeAlso({MyException.class})
public class MyException2 extends MyException {
    public MyException2() {
       super("asd");
    }
    public String msg = "blablbasldk";

}
```

When I generate wsdl and xsd it has definition for MyException2 class, which has only public property defined in MyException2 class. I would like to generate xsd which will contain definition of MyException2 which will have all public properties - from MyException and also from MyException2 class.

It is possible? I find that @XmlSeeAlso should work but it is not.. :( thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
It is working but with new version of apache-cfx 2.7.7 
Now it generate MyException2 class in xsd which has attributes from both classes